# Git submodule created by other team member

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have added a submodule and checked in this submodule fully, I have then checked in my master project.

Now my team mate who had checked out the master project before i added a submodule only gets an empty folder for the submodule.

he can do recursive checkout of master project and get submodule.
But we don't want a new checkout because he has changes, so we simply want the submodule to show up in his project as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thought is that he could `git stash save` his changes, do a recursive checkout to get the changes and then `git stash pop` to keep going.

I would test this out first to make sure it works how you expect it too.

Comment: ahh stash... i will give that a try.